# How to play Clash of Clans in Windows phone

Tags: games

Is there any chance of getting an update in windows phone to play clash of clans. In my desktop I use blue stacks to play. Is there any other way to play in my phone.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developer/publisher of Clash of Clans?

Comment: ha ha  ha...!!! I am here asking for doubts...not to make fun of you guys...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the developer doesn't support this officially you can't play the game on Windows Phone / Mobile. 
Microsoft has removed the Android subsystem from Windows 10 Mobile (previews) so there's no currently no way to run apps that weren't built for Windows.

Your best bet is certainly contacting the developer.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to ask developers of the game about that.

There exist a small chance that somebody will do reverse-engineering of API and create Windows Phone app without permission of authors. But it is very hard and risky